# Which user permissions are needed for accessing (read) operational attributes in openldap

Tags: openldap, user-permissions

I'm configuring at the moment a openldap server. For defining user permissions I use a ldif file. For checking the permissions and to see if all works like expected I use the Apache Directory Studio.

One requirement for the user permissions is, that a user can read its own entry, a local administrator can read all user entries in his branch and a "global" admin can read all user entries. So far so good everything works.

Additional I need to know to which groups a user belongs. For that I wanted to use the operational attribute `memberOf` which is supported by openldap. Unfortunately only the "global" administrator is able to see operational attributes. If I try to fetch operational attributes within Apache Directory Studio using a local administrator or a simple user no operational attribute will be displayed/fetched.

I tried to give those users the read permission for all member-attributes where their dn is entered with the following rule:

```
olcAccess: to attrs=member,entry
     by dnattr=member selfwrite
     by * break
```

This rule is similiar to the one at the end of the [openldap documentation, chapter 8.3.5](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html). This doesn't seem to work at all, so I tried to add a general rule to access the role entries:

```
olcAccess: to dn.regex="ou=Roles,dc=([^,]+),dc=customers,dc=domain,dc=de$" attrs=entry,@groupOfNames,children
     by group.expand="cn=Administrators,ou=Roles,dc=$1,dc=customers,dc=domain,dc=de" write
     by group.expand="cn=ProductionUser,ou=Roles,dc=$1,dc=customers,dc=domain,dc=de" read   
     by group.expand="cn=TestUser,ou=Roles,dc=$1,dc=customers,dc=domain,dc=de" read
     by * break
```

With this rule any user can read all role entries for his branch. The operational attributes or at least `memberOf` will still not be visible for the users.

So what permissions do I need to grant so that every user can read at least the `memberOf`-attribute for its own entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my attempt was to complicated. With a general access rule to everything for `self` everything seems to work as wished:

```
olcAccess: to * 
     by self read
```

With that rule every user can read everything that relates to the own entry (and not only the own entry itself) including the operational attributes.